# Xamarin different splashscreen tablet and phone

Tags: android, xamarin, dynamic-splash-screen

We have a big xamarin project. We have multiple splashscreens, for phone and for tablet. The splashscreens have a logo on them, which can't be stretched. You can put a splashscreen in the drawable folders, but then you can't detect if its a tablet or phone.

How is it possible to configure multiple splashscreens, not only based on the drawable folders? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Although this may not be the fix you are looking for, I can suggest looking at the Xamarin guide for [detecting screen density](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/device_specific/detect_screen_size/) . Here you can set a certain threshold (certain number of pixels in height and width means it is a tablet) and set one of two drawables you have. One splash screen for tablets and the other for phones.

I don't know what the splash screen looks like, but if it is simply the logo that is important (say if you have a solid color background) possibly make a layout that fills the screen with a background color and center_horizontal + center_vertical your logo drawable (that way you only need one drawable for all splash screens)